# Singular values and singular vector pair for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the singular values and singular vector pairs for a matrix $1_{1\times q}\otimes w_{p\times 1}$? Here $1_{1\times q}$ is the row vector of all ones,  $w_{p\times 1}$ is an arbitrary column vector of complex entries and $\otimes$ represents the Kronecker product of two matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix can be written more simply as 
$$
w_{p \times 1} 1_{q \times 1}^T = \sqrt{n}\cdot \|w\|\cdot \hat w {\hat 1}{}^T
$$
Where $\hat u$ denotes $u/\|u\|$. This is a rank 1 matrix.

The singular values of this matrix are $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{n}\|w\|$ and $\sigma_2 = \cdots = \sigma_p = 0$.

We have $u_1 = \hat 1 $ and $v_1 = \hat w$.  For $i \geq 2$, the only requirement is that the vectors $u_i$ form an orthonormal basis of $1 ^\perp$, while the $v_i$ for an orthonormal basis of $w^\perp$.